# Let $\{A_n|n \in \mathbb{N}\}$ be a countable family of connected subsets of topological space $X$ $\ldots$

Tags: general-topology

Let $\{A_n|n \in \mathbb{N}\}$ be a countable family of connected subsets of topological space $X$. Show that if $A_n$ and $A_{n+1}$ are not seperated for all $n$, then $\cup_{n=1}^\infty A_n$ is connected.

How to prove this.

Please suggest something !???

Comment: Please do not title questions this way. Be more concrete.

Answer (score 2):

If $A_n$ and $A_{n+1}$ are not separated, than there exist $x \in cl(A_n) \cap cl(A_{n+1})$. This means that the set $A_{n} \cup A_{n+1}$ is connected. By arguing this infinitely times we get to your answer.